# How can I make a hover command = a shape upon hover?

Tags: html, css, adobe-illustrator

The idea is to have normal text until someone mouses over, then I want a shape (which ideally I would import out of Illustrator as an .svg). So when someone mouses over "CLICK HERE" a shape would appear instead of just a color or opacity change.

Can this be done using HTML and CSS?

Comment: Sure, you can set the SVG as a background.

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with something like this:

```css
.foo{
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  transition: background-color 1s ease;
}

.foo:hover{
      text-indent: -9999px;
      background-color: red;
      height: 200px;
      border-radius: 50%;    
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
click here
</div>
```

If you need further help just post more details of what you want.

Comment: So I want my text "about me" to appear white until i hover over it, then i want it to have a background of an .svg i saved off from Illustrator.

i tried your code on my text and it worked great, but i want to import the image shape instead of creating it with css.